# Django Banners in Admin

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

Hi I am looking for advice on setting up side banners on my Django app that can be edited through the admin panel, in a similar way to Wordpress where I can just insert the link into the primary sidebar. I have searched the net extensively and still can't find anything to point me in the right direction. I checked Django-ads but the documentation is a little hard to follow, so I am wondering if anyone has any suggestions for a simpler solution.
I would like the following functionality
- Create custom banner from admin panel
- Ability to resize 
- Preferably ability to add multiple different types/sizes

I understand that this question is a little vague / no example, but if anyone has done something similar I would greatly appreciate a nudge in the right direction.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What I would do would be to create a model and a middleware. The middleware would call the model and create the html. I would then add it to the proper template files.

Answer (score 0):

You can add "description" key onto fieldsets attribute inside admin.py of your app, like:

```
from django.contrib import admin

class AdminClass(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = ((None,{"fields":<fields_list>,"description":"Your banner"},))
```

To decorate with html styles, also you can:

```
from django.utils.html import format_html

...,"description":format_html("<html_tags style='[styles]'>Your Banner</html_tags>")},)))
```

And register

```
admin.site.register(YourModel,AdminClass)
```